# Get list of videos including private/unlisted using contentOwnerId

Tags: youtube-api

I was using `playlistitems` to get the authenticated users' video list (including private/unlisted).

Now I tried contentOwnerId. I can get private video info using `onBehalfOfContentOwner`, but there is no `onBehalfOfContentOwner` key for `playlistitems`.

Is there other way to get the full list of an owned channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that the expected way of doing this is via `search.list(part=snippet, forContentOwner=true, onBehalfOfContentOwner=CONTENT_OWNER_ID, type=video, maxResults=50)` and optionally including `channelId=UC...` if you just want to get the videos in a specific channel you manage. You'd have to request multiple pages if there are more than 50 videos. I just tested that out and it does appear to return private as well as public videos.

Yes, it's kind of odd that this is done via `search.list()` and not `playlistItems.list()`...

Comment: It's likely that the engineering team will add support for `onBehalfOfContentOwner=` to `playlistItems.list()` in the future.